# Clover does not create database

Tags: java, maven, clover

I'm trying to run Clover to see test coverage, but it will not create any database (and thus not give any report).

Among others, I've tried to run

```
mvn clean clover2:setup clover2:instrument clover2:clover clover2:check
```

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
    <configuration>

        <!--  <cloverDatabase>C:\clover\clover.db</cloverDatabase>  -->                              
        <!--    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/testreports</reportsDirectory>  -->   
        <targetPercentage>10%</targetPercentage>
        <includes>
            <include>**Test.java</include>
            <include>**IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
                <goal>check</goal>
                <goal>setup</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've run with and without the `<cloverDatabase>` and `<reportsDirectory>` properties. No difference.

No database is ever created anywhere. Why?

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/maven-clover2-plugin/2.3.1/instrument-mojo.html), try removing `<phase>verify</phase>` and running `mvn clean install`.

Comment: No Clover database found, skipping test coverage verification

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working again by removing Clover, and then adding Clover back with only simple settings

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetPercentage>70%</targetPercentage>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

If I try to add inclusion specifications, then suddenly it won't create any db anymore....